Automatically add timestamp to a cell if another cell has any text in it
I need Excel to add a time stamp to a cell (Let's say D1) if another cell (Let's say A1) have any text entered into it. We have a PC setup that we will scan items using a hand scanner set up as a keyboard in our storage as either "IN " or "OUT ". When an item is scanned into cell A1 the timestamp will automatically be inserted into cell D1. Is there a formula for it, or do I need to set a macro using VB.

You need VBA coding.

You may try the following codes.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target <> "" Then
            Target.Offset(, 3) = Now()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

